# Form - new page on submit button

Tags: forms, submit

Last year i build a form for one of our costumers, when visitors submitted the form they
got a message on the same page. But now he asks me if it is possible to 
make a succes page if the form is filled in correctly.

I can't make it work. It's a bit out of my league.

So i hope anyone of you can help me out!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#ajax-contact-form").submit(function() {
        $('#load').append('<center><img src="ajax-loader.gif" alt="Currently Loading" id="loading" /></center>');

        var fem = $(this).serialize(),
            note = $('#note');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "contact/contact2.php",
            data: fem,
            success: function(msg) {
                if ( note.height() ) {          
                    note.slideUp(500, function() { $(this).hide(); });
                } 
                else note.hide();

                $('#loading').fadeOut(300, function() {
                    $(this).remove();

                    // Message Sent? Show the 'Thank You' message and hide the form
                    result = (msg === 'OK') ? '<div class="success">Uw bericht is verzonden, we nemen z.s.m. contact met u op!</div>' : msg;


                    var i = setInterval(function() {
                        if ( !note.is(':visible') ) {
                            note.html(result).slideDown(500);
                            clearInterval(i);
                        }
                    }, 40);    
                }); // end loading image fadeOut
            }
        });

        return false;
    });


    <form id="ajax-contact-form" target="_blank" method="post" action="javascript:alert('success!');" >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of displaying the "success" message, redirect to a new page:

```
window.location = successPageUrl;
```

Comment: Thank you! Where should i put this? I tried various locations. The result is that whenever i touch the submit button it goes to a new page. Even if the form is giving an error.

Comment: Like this: $.ajax.....success: function(msg) { window.location = successPageUrl; }

Answer (score 0):

Just redirect to success page after ajax success.